# 読み込みと表示について

Tags: c++

演習1ー5が書けなくて困ってます。まだ始めたてなので教えてください

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

実行結果に自分が入力した数字を入れられなくて困ってます

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
｛
int no;
printf(“整数を入力してください。\n”);
scanf(“%d”,&no);

printf(“に12を加えると%dです。\n”,12+no);

return 0;

｝
```

Comment: ご自身が書いたコードを質問に追記していただくと、どこで躓いているのかわかりますので回答が付きやすいと思います。エラーとなっていていも構わないので追記は可能でしょうか？

Comment: 引用箇所は画像でなく、テキストとして質問に記入して下さい。
それにより検索なども可能になります。
また、引用元（書籍ならば書籍名など）も明示してください。

Comment: プログラムの実行の結果(や入力の与え方)はどのような環境で実行するのかによっても変わってきます。OSや使っているIDEまたはエディタ、どのようにコンパイルし起動しているのかなど、環境に関する情報をご質問に記入してください。

Comment: @OOPer  質問者さんは（書籍通り？） `stdio` を使っているようですし、OSの差異などは気にせず大丈夫だと思いますよ。

Comment: @mjy さん、今までどれくらいのIDEを使ってこられましたか? IDEによっては通常のターミナルアプリ通りのことをやっても標準入力が読み取れないことはありますが?

Comment: @OOPer なるほど。
そもそも `scanf` が失敗しているという可能性は考えていませんでした。
質問者さんに、OS によりプログラムの修正の仕方が異なるという誤解を与えるのでは、と思ったためコメントしました。

Comment: @mjy さん、なるほど確かに質問者さんに必要以上にいろんな可能性を想像させてしまう書き方だったかもしれませんね。私的には user17014 さんが具体的に説明してくださった点を修正するだけでOKの可能性が一番高いとは思うのですが、一部のブラウザではテキストの自動修正機能が働くせいでこのサイトに書き込まれた時に変化してしまったと言う可能性も捨て切れません。もしそうだとしたら、環境や実行の際の手順をできるだけ詳しく書いてもらえれば、可能性を絞り込めるかと思います。可能性の高い回答が、「いや違う」と言われてから「どう違うんだ、もっと説明してみろ」と言うより、早めに質問に十分な記述をしてもらえれば、質問者にも回答者にも余計な手間を書けさせることなく、未来の読者にとっても自分が抱えている問題とこの質問が同じことなのかどうかわかりやすいと言うメリットがあるだろうと考えています。質問者さんに誤解を与えにくいような表現は今後も考え続けていきたいとは思いますが、意図の方はご理解いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

```
printf(“に12を加えると%dです。\n”,12+no);
```

を

```
printf("%dに12を加えると%dです。\n",no, 12+no);
```

にすれば解決すると思います。
詳しくはprintfの使い方とフォーマット指定子を調べてください。

その書籍がなんだかわかりませんが、基本的なことなのでその書籍内でもどこかで説明があると思います。

Answer (score 0):

実行するにはコンパイルを行っているはずですが、コンパイルを行った際に何かメッセージは出ていませんか？

質問文に貼ってあるプログラムは`{`, `}`や`"`などが全角記号で入力されており、実際のソースコードも全角のままだとするとコンパイルの段階でエラーになります。

これらの記号を半角に直してコンパイルをしたところ、生成されたプログラム(`a.out`)を実行した分には特に問題ありませんでした。